# How to export image from Orca for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, setup-project, orca

I am working on Visual Studio 2010 Setup project.Now as per my requirement i have change the BannerBitmap and SplashBitmap image permanently and update it with my custom Images.For this i have got a wonderfull Article here [Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34086/Setup-Dialogs-Own-BannerBitmap-and-SplashBitmap).Followed to which i downloaded `Orca` and changed the image accordingly but its not getting reflected into my Setup.Later on my search i got to know that i can export the images using the Orca but i am not getting to know how?I want this so that i can see if my image is saved there or not?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Open the MSI file with Orca. Go to the Binary table. There should be a row there with the name DefBannerBitmap. If you double click the [Binary Data] cell you'll get a dialog and you can write the file to disk from there.

Comment: First of all I thank You for your answer.I tried the way suggested by you and getting dialogue box that contains two option as Action `1.Read Binary from Filename`  and `2.write binary to filename` but both the options are in disabled mode.So i am not able to perform the action.Please help.

Comment: The MSI file has the Readonly attribute set, that's why. Reset it.

Comment: Right click the MSI file, Properties, te Readonly bit will be set. That makes those radiobuttons disabled when I test this.